# Integers not getting added up correctly but doubles are working fine

Tags: c++, templates, int, double

I know this isnt the right kind of question to be asking, but for the life of me I could not figure out what is causing this problem.

I need to write a problem that takes a set number of integers or doubles and returns their sum.

I have written the code to make this work, making sure to check each time I changed something.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class totalClass
{
private:
T *p;
T Total;
T sum;
int size;
public:
        T total(int x)
{
    size = x;
    p = new T[x];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        p[i] = T();

    if (size > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            cin >> sum;
            Total += sum;
        }
    }
    return Total;
}
};

int main()
{
int size, result1;
double result2;

cout << "Enter: ";
cin >> size;

cout << "the number of ints you wish to enter: Enter: " << size << " integers:";
totalClass<int> test;
result1 = test.total(size);
cout << " Total = " << result1 << endl;

cout << "Enter: ";
cin >> size;

cout << "the number of doubles you wish to enter: Enter: " << size << " doubles:";
totalClass<double> test2;
result2 = test2.total(size);
cout << " Total = " << result2 << endl;
}
```

My doubles are getting added up correctly but my integer addition always seems to add up to some crazy number. Is there something wrong with my problem that I cannot see?

Comment: I don't think you initialized `Total`.

Comment: ....thank you... I cant believe it was that simple.

Comment: Smells like _undefined behavior_ (like rotten fish)

Answer (score 0):

If you forget to initialize a variable and attempt to use it or do math with it, you might end up with "crazy numbers." Make sure all of your variables are Initialized.